# incompatible types found : void, what is wrong?

Tags: java, types, vector, void

I am trying to write a class that find the closest two vectors and return a sum.

I have tried to understand so hard but I can't find the reason why I get this message, it's the only error I get:

java:93: incompatible types
found   : void
required: EDU.gatech.cc.is.util.Vec2
        result = one.add(two);
                        ^

Line 93 is at the end of the code, I put some arrows to indicate it!

```
enter code here


package EDU.gatech.cc.is.clay;


import java.util.*;
import EDU.gatech.cc.is.clay.*;
import java.lang.*;
import EDU.gatech.cc.is.abstractrobot.*;
import EDU.gatech.cc.is.util.Vec2;
import EDU.gatech.cc.is.util.Units;


public class MAX_go_in_between extends NodeVec2
{
  public static final boolean DEBUG = /*true;*/ Node.DEBUG;
  private SocSmall abstract_robot;


  public MAX_go_in_between(SocSmall ar)
  {
    abstract_robot = ar;


  }

  long last_spott = 0;
  Vec2 result = new Vec2();



  public Vec2 Value(long timestamp)
  {


    if (DEBUG) System.out.println("MAX_Avoid_walls: Value()");

    if ((timestamp > last_spott) || (timestamp == -1))
    {
      if (timestamp != -1) last_spott = timestamp;


      Vec2 one;
      Vec2 two;

      //array of Vec2 of all the opponents
      Vec2[] list_opp = abstract_robot.getOpponents(timestamp);
      //empty array of vec2 where will be put the opponents in front of the robot
      ArrayList<Vec2> list_opp_in_front;

      Vec2 temp;


      // find which opponents are in front and put them in the arraylist
      for(int i=0; i<list_opp.length; i++)
      {
        temp = list_opp[i];

        if(temp.x >= 0.0)
        {
          list_opp_in_front.add(temp);
        }
      }

      //get closest opponent and sets it to index 0
      for(int i=1; i<list_opp_in_front.size()-1; i++)
      {
        temp = list_opp_in_front.get(i);

          if(list_opp_in_front.get(0).r<temp.r)
        {
          list_opp_in_front.set(i, list_opp_in_front.get(0));
          list_opp_in_front.set(0, temp);

        }
      }

      //get second closest opponent and sets it to index 1
      for(int i=2; i<list_opp_in_front.size()-1; i++)
      {
        temp = list_opp_in_front.get(i);

          if(list_opp_in_front.get(1).r<temp.r)
        {
          list_opp_in_front.set(i, list_opp_in_front.get(1));
          list_opp_in_front.set(1, temp);
        }

          // sum both vectors
          one = list_opp_in_front.get(0);
          two = list_opp_in_front.get(1);

 =============>>>>
 =============>>>>   result = one.add(two);
          }

      }

      return(result);
    }

  }



Here is the Vec2.add(Vec2) method:


 public void add(Vec2 other)
  {
  x = x + other.x;
  y = y + other.y;
  r = Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y);
  if (r > 0)
   t = Math.atan2(y,x);
  }
```

Comment: How about pointing out which is line 93. Also, what is the declaration of the method `Vec2.add(Vec2)`?

Comment: Please share `add` method declaration from `Vec2`.

Answer (score 4):

```
result = one.add (two);
public void add (Vec2 other)
//     ^^^^
```

From this, the member function `add` does not return anything that you can put into `result`. With a line like:

```
x = x + other.x;
```

(where `x` is a member of "the current object" and `other` is the object you're adding to it), it's a dead certainty that `one.Add (two)` is meant to *modify* `one` rather than just *use* it in a calculation.

So, rather than:

```
one = list_opp_in_front.get (0);
two = list_opp_in_front.get (1);
result = one.add (two);
```

you'll probably need something like:

```
result = list_opp_in_front.get (0);
two = list_opp_in_front.get (1);
result.add (two);
```

Comment: Ok, I've indicated line 93 with arrows and added the Vec2.add(Vec2),

thank you for your quick answer! I am not used to asking questions here yet, sorry about this!

Answer (score 0):

As per your method declaration `public void add(Vec2 other)`, you are adding `two` into `one`. Thus **`one` itself is your result, hence there no need of return.**

just remove the return statement and treat `one` as result object.

Comment: @Negative User: Please leave some comment to help understand what's wrong with the answer?