# Java 8 sort list of objects

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, incompatibletypeerror

I am trying to sort my list of objects like this:

```
List<UsersDataFoundTo> mergedUsers = mergeUsersFound(ldapUsers, foundUsers);
return mergedUsers.sort((UsersDataFoundTo h1, UsersDataFoundTo h2) -> h1.getLastName().compareTo(h2.getLastName()));
```

and on the return statement I get an error:

```
Incompatible types.
Required: java.util.List<UsersDataFoundTo>
Found:void
```

What do I do wrong then?

Comment: `sort` has no return value.

Comment: As @Eran says, sort it, and then return the list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [incompatible types found : void, what is wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12907124/incompatible-types-found-void-what-is-wrong)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Much easier would be to write is as:

```
mergedUsers.sort(Comparator.comparing(UsersDataFoundTo::getLastName))
```

And `sort` has a `void` return type, so basically do a :

```
return mergedUsers;
```

Answer (score 2):

For reusable, I think the class UsersDataFoundTo should implements Comparable and override compareTo function.

```
class UsersDataFoundTo implements Comparable<UsersDataFoundTo> {
    private String lastNam;

    public String getLastNam() {
        return lastNam;
    }

    public void setLastNam(String lastNam) {
        this.lastNam = lastNam;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(UsersDataFoundTo other) {
        return getLastNam().compareTo(other.getLastNam());
    }
}
```

Then you can use a collection utility to sort it like this:

```
List<UsersDataFoundTo> mergedUsers = //...
java.util.Collections.sort(mergedUsers);
```

I hope this help.

Comment: And if he changes his mind and try to compare on another property `UsersDataFoundTo` !!